# WinUI3 ComboBox and Button have different size

Tags: xaml, winui-3

we have a `ComboBox` and a `Button` next to eachother. They are in the same `Grid.Row`in two different `Grid.Columns`.

However they both appeared to have a different size. Even by setting `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` this did not change.

Last but not least I set an fixed height to both elements but they are still not the same size.

How dows that come and how can I change it?

[Here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUrk8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works on my sample app.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="1"
        ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
        RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
        <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            CornerRadius="0"
            SelectedIndex="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Auswahlen" />
        </ComboBox>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            CornerRadius="0">
            <FontIcon
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                Glyph="&#xE819;" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I exactly copied your code (the only thing I added was a Grid.Row="0" to the grid element to place it correctly in my application but sadly the two elements still have a different size if I use VerticalAlignment="Stretch"

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry. Just setting ``VerticalAlignment`` to ``Stretch`` should do work.

Comment: Sadly the problem does still exist if you say that it works in your sample app it might be a problem residing deeper in the application that I#ve to look into.

Comment: Weird. This should be an easy fix. Can you share a reproducible project on GitHub? or Your ``Page``or ``Window`` with minimal code?

Comment: Will look at it when I find time!